# join two files and fill a new column according to another column

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have these two files:

**first file**: `'ast'`

*columns*: `fid,CAD_ADMIN`

**second file**: `'inte'`

*columns*: `Left_Ln, Right_Ln`

---

**Purpose**

I want to do a join with `fid` and `Left_Ln` and  fill a new column in the `inte` file called `Left_enot` with the `CAD_ADMIN` column of the first file.

**Attempt**

```
ast = pd.read_csv(directory,encoding = 'UTF-8')
inte = pd.read_csv(directory,encoding = 'UTF-8')
ast.reset_index(inplace= True)
ast.rename(columns = {'index': 'FID'},inplace = True)
final = pd.merge(ast, inte, on = ['FID'], how = 'inner')
final
```

This doesn't do what I need. How can I do that?

Comment: Python never lies. Have you tried 'fid' instead of 'FID' ?

Comment: but the name is capital. Anyway yes but it didn't work.

Comment: @CorentinLimier Maybe is the fact that it doesn't exist in both files?Apparently it is.Anyway, I bet my way is not even the right approach. How can I do the join I described above? Thanks

Comment: can you post sample dataframe and an expected output dataframe plz

Comment: @user10389994 merge method has two optional parameters left_on and right_on if dataframes do not share same key name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need `left_on='FID', right_on="Left_Ln"`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd


ast = pd.read_csv(filename,encoding = 'UTF-8')
inte = pd.read_csv(filename1,encoding = 'UTF-8')
ast.reset_index(inplace= True)
ast.rename(columns = {'index': 'FID_1'},inplace = True)
final = pd.merge(ast, inte, left_on='FID', right_on="Left_Ln", how='inner')
print(final)
```

Comment: Can you add the part about 'and fill a new column in the inte file called Left_enot with the CAD_ADMIN column of the first file." too?

Comment: `inte["newCol"] = final["CAD_ADMIN"]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this instead:

```
ast = pd.read_csv(directory,encoding = 'UTF-8')
inte = pd.read_csv(directory,encoding = 'UTF-8')
final = pd.merge(inte, ast, left_index=True, right_on='fid',how='left').drop('fid',axis=1)
final.rename(columns={'CAD_ADMIN':'Left_enot'},inplace=True)
```

Comment: Didn't work. It needs to do the join with these two columns. fid from first  and Left_Ln from second

Comment: can you provide sample view of both dataframes

Comment: Can you test this and tell? I have updated the answer